# how to set default keyboard cursor in mac terminal to start with 'one space' after $ sign?

Tags: macos, terminal

Hi I would like my mac os terminal cursor to begin where **c** is.

Current: MJ@JEONui-MacBook-Pro.local:~$**c**

Preferred: MJ@JEONui-MacBook-Pro.local:~$ **c**

In other words, I would like the cursor to start with one spacing after :.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Go to your root directory and open your `.bash_profile` in a text editor (if you don't have one, do `touch .bash_profile` and then open it.
2) Add the following line:

```
export PS1='\u@\H:\w$ '
```

3) Note that there is a space between the dollar sign and the end quote.
4) Restart your terminal.

For your information, the `u` is for user, the `H` is for host, and the `w` is the path name. You can customize this to read however you want, according to [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/bash-shell-ps1-10-examples-to-make-your-linux-prompt-like-angelina-jolie/).

P.S. you should use [oh-my-zsh](http://ohmyz.sh/) :-D for lots of reasons like this!